# Filtrar select para que resultado no muestre todos los registros

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
codigo / signo /importe
```

Con este select obtengo los siguiente:

```
codigo / cargo / abono / saldo
```

Pero quiero que no muestre los que tienen saldo cero (0), cómo filtro eso?

```
SELECT codigo,
SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) cargo,
SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) abono,
SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN import ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
FROM tabla
group by codigo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  codigo,
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) cargo,
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) abono,
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN import ELSE 0 END) - 
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
FROM tabla
GROUP BY codigo
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN import ELSE 0 END) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) <> 0
;
```

O una tabla derivada:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT  codigo,
                SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) cargo,
                SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) abono,
                SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN import ELSE 0 END) - 
                SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
        FROM tabla
        GROUP BY codigo) as t
WHERE t.saldo <> 0;
```